# Store DateTime column in h2 database by hibernate

Tags: java, angularjs, spring, hibernate, h2

I want to store DateTime column in h2 database by hibernate ,spring mvc and angularJs I can save the following date format 2015-01-14  but I want to store this format 2015-01-14 21:32:29 but I get this error 
POST http://loclhost:8080/pagingpoc/app/rest/contacts [HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request 24ms]

field declaration in entity

```
@Column(name = "updatetimestamp", nullable = false)
@Type(type = "org.jadira.usertype.dateandtime.joda.PersistentDateTime")
private DateTime  updatetimestamp;
```

Column name and type in database table

```
        <column name="UpdateTimestamp" type="timestamp"/>
```

Spring controller

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/rest/contacts",
        method = RequestMethod.POST,
        produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
@Timed
public void create(@RequestBody Contact contact) {
    contactRepository.save(contact);
}
```

AngularJS  service

```
pagingpocApp.factory('Contact', function ($resource) {
    return $resource('app/rest/contacts/:id', {}, {
        'query': { method: 'GET', isArray: true},
        'get': { method: 'GET'}
    });
});
```

AngularJS controller

```
  $scope.create = function () {
            Contact.save($scope.contact,
                function () {
                    $scope.contacts = Contact.query();
                    $('#saveContactModal').modal('hide');
                    $scope.clear();
                });
        };
```

Html page

```
 <div class="form-group">
            <label>Update Timestamp</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control"
            ng-model="contact.updatetimestamp">
  </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should enter DateTime in this format 2015-01-14T21:32:29